# how to use session variable when the user is not logged in yet for navigation menu

Tags: php

I am trying to show different contents in the navigation menu if the user is either an admin or moderator or a normal user but I can't figure out how to do it because I can't use the session variable because the user is not logged in yet

I tried to do this by using the session variable but then realised that the user is not logged in. I am assuming that I have to include it in the php section in order for this to work as I would like to split up the contents in the navigation menu

```
 <?php 
session_start();
include_once __DIR__.'/includes/dbh.php';
$admin = 1;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE admin = ?;";

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                            //Prepare the prepared statement
                            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                                echo 'SQL statement failed';
                            } else {
                                 //Bind parameters to the placeholder
                                 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i",$admin);
                                 //Run parameters inside database
                                 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                                 $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                                 $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                                 if($resultCheck > 0) {
                                     echo '<div class="nav">
       <input type="checkbox" id="menu" />
       <label for="menu" id="nav-icon">&#9776;</label>

       <div class="multi-level">
          <div class="item">
             <input type="checkbox" id="A" />
             <div class="arrow"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></div><label for="A">Home</label>
             <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home Page</a></li>

             </ul>
          </div>
          <li><div class="sub-item">
                       <input type="checkbox" id="B-A" />
                       <div class="arrow"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></div><label for="B-A">Administrator\'s Section</label>

                       <ul>
                         <li><a href="create_music_cat.php">Create Music Category</a></li>
                           <li><a href="create_music_sub.php">Create Music Sub Category</a></li>
                           <li><a href="admin_create_music_topic.php">Create Music Topic</a></li>
                           <li><a href="admin_nonpremium_users.php">Display Non Premium Users</a></li>
                           <li><a href="admin_level1_users.php">Display Level 1 Premium Users</a></li>
                            <li><a href="admin_level2_users.php">Display Level 2 Premium Users</a></li>
                             <li><a href="admin_level3_users.php">Display Level 3 Premium Users</a></li>
                             <li><a href="admin_level1_overdue_users.php">Display Level 1 Overdue Users</a></li>
                             <li><a href="admin_level2_overdue_users.php">Display Level 2 Overdue Users</a></li>
                             <li><a href="admin_level3_overdue_users.php">Display Level 3 Overdue Users</a></li>
                             <li><a href="ticket.php">Ticket Reply</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact_moderators.php">Contact Moderators</a></li>
                       </ul>
                    </div></li>
                     <div class="item">
             <input type="checkbox" id="B" />
            <div class="arrow"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></div><label for="B">Members\' Section</label>
             <ul>


                        <li><div class="sub-item">
                       <input type="checkbox" id="B-C" />
                       <div class="arrow"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></div><label for="B-C">Watch Videos</label>
                       <ul>
                          <li><a href="primer.php">Primer Videos</a></li>
                          <li><a href="level1.php">Level 1 Videos</a></li>
                          <li><a href="level2.php">Level 2 Videos</a></li>
                          <li><a href="level3.php">Level 3 Videos</a></li>
                       </ul>
                    </div></li>

                    <li><a href="practice_diary.php">Practice Diary</a></li>
                    <li><a href="display_music_forum.php">Music Forum</a></li>
                    <li><a href="update.php">Student\'s General Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="reward_points.php">Student\'s Reward Points</a></li>
                    <li><a href="donation.php">Donation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="review.php">Write a Review</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ticket_view.php">View Ticket</a></li>

             </ul>
          </div> 
          <div class="item">
             <input type="checkbox" id="C" />
             <div class="arrow"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></div><label for="C">About PianoCourse101</label>

             <ul>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="qa.php">Questions and Answers</a></li>
                <li><a href="activate.php">Activate Membership</a></li>
                <li><a href="reset.php">Change Password</a></li>
             </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <input type="checkbox" id="D" />
            <div class="arrow"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></div><label for="D">Signup</label>

            <ul>
               <li><a href="signup.php">Signup Premium Membership</a></li>
            </ul>
       </div>
   </div>';

        } else {
            $moderator = 1;
            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE moderator = ?;";

            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                            //Prepare the prepared statement
                            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql2)) {
                                echo 'SQL statement failed';
                            } else {
                                 //Bind parameters to the placeholder
                                 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i",$moderator);
                                 //Run parameters inside database
                                 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                                 $result2 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                                 $resultCheck2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);

                                 if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                                    echo '  <div class="nav">
       <input type="checkbox" id="menu" />
       <label for="menu" id="nav-icon">&#9776;</label>

       <div class="multi-level">
          <div class="item">
             <input type="checkbox" id="A" />
             <div class="arrow"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></div><label for="A">Home</label>
             <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home Page</a></li>

             </ul>
          </div>
          <li><div class="sub-item">
                       <input type="checkbox" id="B-B" />
                       <div class="arrow"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></div><label for="B-B">Moderator\'s Section</label>

                       <ul>
                          <li><a href="ticket_moderator.php">Ticket Reply</a></li>
                           <li><a href="token_request_primer.php">Token Request: Primer Level</a></li>
                            <li><a href="token_request_level1.php">Token Request: Level 1</a></li>
                             <li><a href="token_request_level2.php">Token Request: Level 2</a></li>
                              <li><a href="token_request_level3.php">Token Request: Level 3</a></li>

                       </ul>
                    </div></li>


               <div class="item">
             <input type="checkbox" id="B" />
            <div class="arrow"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></div><label for="B">Members\' Section</label>
             <ul>


                        <li><div class="sub-item">
                       <input type="checkbox" id="B-C" />
                       <div class="arrow"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></div><label for="B-C">Watch Videos</label>
                       <ul>
                          <li><a href="primer.php">Primer Videos</a></li>
                          <li><a href="level1.php">Level 1 Videos</a></li>
                          <li><a href="level2.php">Level 2 Videos</a></li>
                          <li><a href="level3.php">Level 3 Videos</a></li>
                       </ul>
                    </div></li>

                    <li><a href="practice_diary.php">Practice Diary</a></li>
                    <li><a href="display_music_forum.php">Music Forum</a></li>
                    <li><a href="update.php">Student\'s General Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="reward_points.php">Student\'s Reward Points</a></li>
                    <li><a href="donation.php">Donation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="review.php">Write a Review</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ticket_view.php">View Ticket</a></li>

             </ul>
          </div> 
          <div class="item">
             <input type="checkbox" id="C" />
             <div class="arrow"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></div><label for="C">About PianoCourse101</label>

             <ul>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="qa.php">Questions and Answers</a></li>
                <li><a href="activate.php">Activate Membership</a></li>
                <li><a href="reset.php">Change Password</a></li>
             </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <input type="checkbox" id="D" />
            <div class="arrow"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></div><label for="D">Signup</label>

            <ul>
               <li><a href="signup.php">Signup Premium Membership</a></li>
            </ul>
       </div>
   </div>';


            } else {
                $admin = 1;
                $moderator = 1;
               $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE admin = ? AND moderator = ?;";

                $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                            //Prepare the prepared statement
                            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql3)) {
                                echo 'SQL statement failed';
                            } else {
                                 //Bind parameters to the placeholder
                                 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii",$admin, $moderator);
                                 //Run parameters inside database
                                 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                                 $result3 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                                 $resultCheck3 = mysqli_num_rows($result3);

                                 if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                                     echo '<div class="nav">
       <input type="checkbox" id="menu" />
       <label for="menu" id="nav-icon">&#9776;</label>

       <div class="multi-level">
          <div class="item">
             <input type="checkbox" id="A" />
             <div class="arrow"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></div><label for="A">Home</label>
             <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home Page</a></li>

             </ul>
          </div>
          <li><div class="sub-item">
                       <input type="checkbox" id="B-A" />
                       <div class="arrow"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></div><label for="B-A">Administrator\'s Section</label>

                       <ul>
                         <li><a href="create_music_cat.php">Create Music Category</a></li>
                           <li><a href="create_music_sub.php">Create Music Sub Category</a></li>
                           <li><a href="admin_create_music_topic.php">Create Music Topic</a></li>
                           <li><a href="admin_nonpremium_users.php">Display Non Premium Users</a></li>
                           <li><a href="admin_level1_users.php">Display Level 1 Premium Users</a></li>
                            <li><a href="admin_level2_users.php">Display Level 2 Premium Users</a></li>
                             <li><a href="admin_level3_users.php">Display Level 3 Premium Users</a></li>
                             <li><a href="admin_level1_overdue_users.php">Display Level 1 Overdue Users</a></li>
                             <li><a href="admin_level2_overdue_users.php">Display Level 2 Overdue Users</a></li>
                             <li><a href="admin_level3_overdue_users.php">Display Level 3 Overdue Users</a></li>
                             <li><a href="ticket.php">Ticket Reply</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact_moderators.php">Contact Moderators</a></li>
                       </ul>
                    </div></li>
                     <li><div class="sub-item">
                       <input type="checkbox" id="B-B" />
                       <div class="arrow"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></div><label for="B-B">Moderator\'s Section</label>

                       <ul>
                          <li><a href="ticket_moderator.php">Ticket Reply</a></li>
                           <li><a href="token_request_primer.php">Token Request: Primer Level</a></li>
                            <li><a href="token_request_level1.php">Token Request: Level 1</a></li>
                             <li><a href="token_request_level2.php">Token Request: Level 2</a></li>
                              <li><a href="token_request_level3.php">Token Request: Level 3</a></li>

                       </ul>
                    </div></li>


               <div class="item">
             <input type="checkbox" id="B" />
            <div class="arrow"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></div><label for="B">Members\' Section</label>
             <ul>


                        <li><div class="sub-item">
                       <input type="checkbox" id="B-C" />
                       <div class="arrow"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></div><label for="B-C">Watch Videos</label>
                       <ul>
                          <li><a href="primer.php">Primer Videos</a></li>
                          <li><a href="level1.php">Level 1 Videos</a></li>
                          <li><a href="level2.php">Level 2 Videos</a></li>
                          <li><a href="level3.php">Level 3 Videos</a></li>
                       </ul>
                    </div></li>

                    <li><a href="practice_diary.php">Practice Diary</a></li>
                    <li><a href="display_music_forum.php">Music Forum</a></li>
                    <li><a href="update.php">Student\'s General Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="reward_points.php">Student\'s Reward Points</a></li>
                    <li><a href="donation.php">Donation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="review.php">Write a Review</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ticket_view.php">View Ticket</a></li>

             </ul>
          </div> 
          <div class="item">
             <input type="checkbox" id="C" />
             <div class="arrow"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></div><label for="C">About PianoCourse101</label>

             <ul>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="qa.php">Questions and Answers</a></li>
                <li><a href="activate.php">Activate Membership</a></li>
                <li><a href="reset.php">Change Password</a></li>
             </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <input type="checkbox" id="D" />
            <div class="arrow"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></div><label for="D">Signup</label>

            <ul>
               <li><a href="signup.php">Signup Premium Membership</a></li>
            </ul>
       </div>
   </div>';

                                 } 
                                 }



            } 
        }

}
}


?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>PianoCourse101</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style4.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-/rXc/GQVaYpyDdyxK+ecHPVYJSN9bmVFBvjA/9eOB+pb3F2w2N6fc5qB9Ew5yIns" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: You have to check session is set or not for this scenario

Comment: but how would I do that because the user is not logged in yet... I can't even use the I can't use any sql statement with the user's username

Comment: How can you get the user type (admin or moderator or a normal user)  without login?

Comment: Usually I would do an sql statement based on their username and use the variable $row but in this case, I don't even have their username

Comment: oh wait.... do I need their username.....

Comment: I think i understand

Comment: I would just use... $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE admin = 1";

Comment: I still can't see how this is going to work because if someone has no admin permission and someone else has both admin and moderator, wouldn't this not work because there aren't enough specific information for my sql statement?

Comment: I think I need to add some kind of an if statement to make it work

Comment: You are not using session anywhere in your code

Comment: I know but I can't use session variable because I always get a notice of undefined variable. I think this is because the user is not logged in yet

Comment: there is no way to check for this without using session because the user is not logged in?

Comment: Is there anyway that I can turn off those errors on a live server?

Comment: I can get it to work by using the isset function but must I need to type isset twice here or just once?

Comment: if(isset($_SESSION['u_permission']) == 1 && isset($_SESSION['u_moderator']) == 1)

Comment: I think my bracket is in the wrong place

Comment: I still don't think there is a way to do here because the user is not logged in and therefore I can't use any session variables